# Working with an existing sqlite3 db using moor

Tags: sqlite, flutter, orm

I'm relatively new to flutter and I want to use moor package in an app. I externally created an sqlite db,  insert data into it. Now I want to use that sqlite db in the app and manage db operations with moor. But I can't find a way to do this. Any hint how I can get this done ? An example would be highly helpful.
Thanks in advance.